# How to pass list-like using .reindex as doing it in .loc has been deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas, deprecated

I have a dataframe with multiple fields and I want to use some columns values to recreate a new dataframe as a JSON object:

```
Street      City          State     Zip_Code
24 St.      Kansas City   KS        12345-213
...         ...           ...       ....
```

In order to do so, I was using .loc and .apply like this in python:

```
def address_x(vals):
   val = {
        'street': None if not str(vals[0]) else vals[0],
        'city': None if not str(vals[1]) else vals[1],
        'state': None if not str(vals[2]) else state(vals[2]),
        'postal_code': postal_code(str(vals[3]))
    }
    return val

def transform (dataset):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['address'] = dataset.loc[['Street', 'City', 'State', 'Zip_Code']].apply(address_x, axis=1)
    return df

obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
new_df = transform(pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), delimiter='|', sep='|'))

new_df.to_json('TEST.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

That gives me this error message **KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%27)**

I am trying to use  `df['address'] = dataset.reindex(['STREET', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ZIP CODE']).apply(lambda x: address_x(x))` but just stores all values as **null** instead of this:

```
{"address":{
     "street": "24 St.",
     "city": "Kansas City",
     "state": "Kansas",
     "postal_code": 12345-213}
}
```

The input is a regular csv file that is using '|' as separator and between all columns it has, this are just 4 of them in the example up.

Then I store it as a json and currently the output looks like: `{"address":{"street":null,"city":null,"state":null,"postal_code":null}}` for each record, instead of populating the json with the csv values.

Comment: Please share  a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
def address_x(vals):
    val = {
         'street': None if not str(vals['Street']) else vals['Street'],
         'city': None if not str(vals['City']) else vals['City'],
         'state': None if not str(vals['State']) else state(vals['State']),
         'postal_code': postal_code(str(vals['Zip_Code']))
          }
     return val
 df['address'] = dataset[['Street', 'City', 'State', 'Zip_Code']].apply(address_x, axis=1)
```